# Module not found: Can't resolve 'cluster' when using @rollup/plugin-json

Tags: reactjs, rollup, rollupjs

I am working on a React component library that uses `Babel`+`TypeScript`, and I am using Rollup to create the bundle which I then import components from in a React app.

Everything works fine until I add `json()` from `@rollup/plugin-json` to my `plugins`. After adding that, I end up getting an error that says:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'cluster'
```

Removing this plugin makes the building work again, but then I am unable to do JSON imports like

```js
import config from './config.json'
```

inside my library code. Is there anything extra I need to do to be able to use this plugin or JSON imports in general from a React component library? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

---

My Rollup config:

```js
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import pkg from './package.json';

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                format: 'cjs',
                file: pkg.main,
                sourcemap: true
            },
            {
                format: 'es',
                file: pkg.module,
                sourcemap: true
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal(),
            resolve({ extensions }),
            commonjs(),
            babel({
                extensions,
                babelHelpers: 'runtime',
                exclude: ['node_modules/**']
            }),
            json() // This is the problematic line
        ]
    }
];
```

---

My dependency versions:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
        "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^18.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.1",
        "react": "^16.8",
        "react-dom": "^16.8",
        "rollup": "^2.44.0",
        "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
        "typescript": "^4.2.3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with `@rollup/plugin-json` plugin and I highly recommend you to change your `JSON` configs to a simple `ts` file:

```js
import config from './config';
```

And your file is like:

```js
const config = {
  // ...
};

export default config;
```

Also, I highly recommend you to use [`tsdx`](https://tsdx.io/) for creating your library package, it saves your time a lot. create a new library by using `tsdx` and then migrate all codes to this awesome Zero-Config TypeScript package development.

---

Answer (score 0):

### The error occurs because there has been a breaking change in Webpack V5.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},

  // ️ add this to package.json ️
  "browser": {
    "cluster": false
  }
}
```

[More Info](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-tls)